# post form with ajax and additional json data

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery-ui-dialog

I send a form via jquery ajax. I do not only want to send the values of the formcollection I also want to send another id which is hidden in the page.

How can I send the form data + this id? Maybe there is a way to create one json object and I put everything in it?

```
   jQuery('#myForm').live('submit',function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Url.Action("Create")',
            type: 'POST',           
            data: $('#myForm').serialize(),
            success: function( data ) {

            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If your hidden field is already in the form, It will be in your serialized data.** ***You dont need to send it exclusively***. If you still want to send another piece of data from outside of your form, you may send it as a querystring value and have your action method a parameter named itemId.(Assuming hdnID is the id of your hidden element)

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Create","Home")'+?itemId='+$("#hdnID").val(),
        type: 'POST',           
        data:  $('#myForm').serialize(),              
        success: function( data ) {
        }
     });
```

http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: @Elisa: I believe it will be sent as the querystring. You may read the request parameters in your action method. Use fiddler / firebug /Use Visual studio breakpoints to see what is going in the wire.

Comment: (Post)public ActionResult Create(Teststep teststep,int testplanId), the id is there correctly thanks. But my teststep object is not filled anymore, all 3 properties are empty although I enter data. Somehow the new "feature" broke the mvc model binder. You know how to correct that? EDIT: The teststep object is NOT null, its just that the properties are not filled.BAH... EDIT: sorry for confusion teststep IS NULL. I renamed formData into teststep but did not help!

Comment: ah it seems the "formData" is important because now the teststep object is not null anymore, just the properties are not filled. Thats the code I use: data: { formData: form.serialize(), testplanId: 11 }, The id is always sent correctly?!

Comment: @Elisa: Probably ou should include the id in form or send it asquerystrinng

Comment: great this works! But why does the jquery map not work? I guess I will make that an extra post on SO!